# Importing MySQL Rows into a table

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I was importing some MySQL Rows into a form but there seems to be an issue, the database doesnot connects, it says no database selected, I have my Database connection parameters in constants.php and they are working fine in the other pages of the website, and there is no syntax error in the commands either, Help me please.Thanks!

```
<?php
    require_once 'classes/Membership.php';
    require_once 'includes/constants.php';
    $membership = New Membership();
    $membership->confirm_Member();
    $con = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or 
    die('Error connecting Database');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
        <title>Post Scores | Admin Panel D2C</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="main_body">

        <table width="1029" border="0" cellpadding="0" class="score_table" >
            <td width="131">
            <form align="center" action="update_team_database.php" method="post">
            <tr>

            <td> Team: </td>
            <td width="831">

            <?php 
                $result = mysql_query("select DISTINCT TeamName from team") or die(mysql_error());
                echo '<select name="teamname1"><OPTION>'; 
                echo "Select a team</OPTION>"; 
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                $team1 = $row["TeamName"]; 
                echo "<OPTION value=\"$team1\">$team1</OPTION>";     
            } 
            echo '</SELECT>';
            ?></td>

            </tr>
            </form>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: mysqli or mysql? connection in mysqli why?

Comment: first make sure you have correct database credentials( check DB_NAME by echoing it) in this file and you have mixed up mysqli and mysql. use mysqli_query instead mysql_query.

Comment: Be sure to have no error, use $mysqli->connect_errno  to know

Comment: Yea that was the issue thanks mate :D

Comment: I used mysql instead of mysqli, Problem Solved 

Thank guys ..

Comment: whats the error message? id it "Error connecting Database"? if so check the variables by var dumping them.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you make use of Object Oriented way of performing queries over MySQL using **MySQLi**

You may check the example in here
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Since MySQL is deprecated as of PHP 5.5